# Discord.py message.content.find multiple words

Tags: python, discord.py

Simple question, probably not so simple answer. Can I make the bot answer to more words, not only  "Hi"? In example, `message.content.find` would have multiple words that would execute the event.

Here's the code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content.find("Hi") >= 0:
        channel = message.channel
        await message.channel.send("Hello!")

        def check(m):
            return m.content != "x" and m.channel == channel

        msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
        await message.channel.send("How are you?".format(msg))
```

Comment: "Can I " Well, what happened when you tried doing the most obvious possible thing? Like... "`message.content.find` would have multiple words" what happened when you tried *just putting multiple words there*?

Answer (score 1):

You can also just use the syntax for checking if there is a certain string inside another

Instead of using:

```py
if message.content.find("Hi There") >= 0:
```

You can use:

```py
if "Hi There" in message.content:
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, to your suprise, the answer actually is pretty simple.

```py
if "hi" in message.content:
    # your code goes here
```

Now, with this, we have a problem. If the user says "hi, i am komko" it is gonna trigger the event, but "Hi, i am komko" wouldn't. Why? Well, we are checking for "hi" in the message.content, not "Hi" or "hI", etc...

My approach of doing this was **always** converting the *message.content* to lowercase using `lower()`

Now, it would look:

```py
# we can also make a string declared before, like:
stringValue = "HI"

if stringValue.lower() in message.content.lower():
    # your code goes here
```

This can also be replaced with:

```py
if "Hi".lower() in message.content.lower():
    # your code goes here
```